# HTML5/jQuery: pushstate back issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have in my code the ajax call that loads my content. What I want is to add a deeplinking effect and from my research I found out that only raw coding will do it.
This is what I have so far:

```
jQuery("#sw_layered_cat a").click(function(){
            var url_ajax = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            history.pushState('', '', url_ajax);
});
```

This is working pretty well because the controller of ajax brings the results on my screen, and in another controller I change the url of the page. When it comes to go back to the previous url, I get the correct url but no content is loaded.

No matter what I try I cannot get the previous default url. For example, if I am in *../default/shop/paper.html(1)* and move forward to *../default/shop/paper/paper-pads.html(2)* and press back, I get the correct url (1) but the content is not loading.

I know I have to do something like:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event){ loadPage(//param); }
```

but I cant get the right param.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onpopstate = function () {
  // Something like this. document.location should provide the data you want 
  // at any rate
  loadPage(document.location);
};
```